# bind gridview dynamically with label and tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to bind gridview with datatable in code behind and i want to add label in each cell in gridview and display a tooltip on label of their values... i am not getting tool tip..
(i want to display an each seat of thatre stage) !!! and want to tooltip of it,and my stage 
may change,so i want dynamically)

help me.. my code is here

//Grid view is bind on page load
it gives me Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{


            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {


                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["LabelText"].ToString();
                    lbl.ToolTip = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["TooltipText"].ToString();
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lbl);

                }

            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Label to a cell in each row of the GridView. I would suggest storing the information for the Label and the tooltip in the data key collection, and adding the label in the OnRowDataBound event.

**Option 1:**

**EDIT**: Added markup to show how to add data keys

Define the data keys like in the example below. Replace `LabelTextColumn` and `TooltipTextColumn` with the actual you want to use for the text and the tooltip. Also, notice how the OnRowDataBound event handler is set here:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="LabelTextColumn, TooltipTextColumn" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**EDIT**: Corrected error using RowIndex to get data keys

Since you're in the RowDataBoundEvent, you don't need to use a loop. The `RowDataBound` event is called from within a loop as each row is databound, which is why you have access the current row with `e.Row`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //we don't need this anymore, because the label is already in the row
    //Label lbl = new Label(); 

    //get the label from the row
    Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");

    --set the text and tooltip text using the datakeys specified in the markup
    lbl.Text = grd.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["LabelTextColumn"].ToString();
    lbl.ToolTip = grd.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["TooltipTextColumn"].ToString();

    //we don't need this anymore either, because the label is already added to the row
    //e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

**Option 2:** Using inline Eval() function to set the text and tooltip text

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LabelTextColumn")' Tooltip='<%#Eval("TooltipTextColumn")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thanks for ur help but i am getting tooltip but not the gridview in proper way . can you help me ?? and e.rowindex giving me error  System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'RowIndex' and no extension method 'RowIndex' accepting a first a

Comment: @vivek: Edited my answer. Should have been e.Row.RowIndex. Now what is the other problem that you're having? Where in the GridView do you want the label to show?

Comment: i hv tried e.row.rowindex. ok. i want tooltip on every cell in my gridview please help me from scrach....

Comment: You said you tried e.RowIndex. e.Row.RowIndex definitely works. Are you sure that you're using GridViewRowEventArgs? Revise your question and post your updated code. If you can include some of the markup too, that would be helpful.

Comment: @vivek: See edited answer. Provides a couple ways of doing it. Pay close attention to the code.

Comment: i want labels for each cell. with your code i am getting tooltip for column1 only.in your code what is grd?

Comment: Oh, then just use Option 2 in my answer, and add Labels for each column, add use the databinding syntax to set the text and tooltip for each column.

Comment: in my case option 2 is not the answer. because no. of columns in my table arent fix. so i cant take labels for each columns.i want it dynamically in .cs ?? so what to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

When you databind, it destroys the current control collection and populates with the provided data source.

For your specific application, you would also need to attach to the `GridView.RowCreated` event and then insert the tooltip you need.

Comment: i draw a stage table in database.i want to display whole table in gridview with each cell having a tooltip. can u help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in a handler for the [Gridview.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).